# How do I properly add parameters to program called within a windows command shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts, console, command-line-arguments

How do I properly add parameters to program called in a windows command shortcut?

Passing parameters to the console alone, is trivial:

`cmd.exe /h`

... but what if you want to both open a console && then pass parameters to a program called in that console?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows shortcut using the following target:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws.exe" --version`

... everything after the /k will be "passed" to the console & executed.  Hence, in this example `/k` and every parameter before the `/k` will be passed to `cmd.exe`, whereas `--version` will be the parameter to the console program `aws.exe`.  This will return something similar to:

```
    aws-cli/2.2.18 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

    C:\dev\aws\cli>
```

Note:  If you use `/c` instead of `/k`, when the console program terminates, the console will close as well.  `/k` keeps it the console window open upon termination (my preference)

Here's a link to the Microsoft Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd